# MySQL ORDER BY not showing the last row

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, coalesce

I have the following query:

```
MySQL_Query(
    "SELECT COALESCE(`from`,`to`) AS `userid`, `id`, `from`, `to`, `type`, `datum`, `read`, `message` 
     FROM `messages` 
     WHERE `to`='".$user->id."' 
     AND `from` NOT IN 
        (SELECT `user` FROM `ignore` WHERE `idu`='".$user->id."') 
     OR `from`='".$user->id."' 
     GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY `id` DESC"
);
```

The highest ID that I have is 128, but PHP returns the row with ID=5. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the id field is an integer because in varchar 5 is bigger than 128?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(60) COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs NOT NULL,
  `datum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emotion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(60) COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs NOT NULL,
  `nazev` text COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs NOT NULL,
  `cesta` text COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250 COLLATE=cp1250_czech_cs AUTO_INCREMENT=188 ;